# Octave command window showing unreadable text

Tags: octave

When I start Octave, on the command window I see this:

[image: Octave command window]

However, after I run some commands, I can see they are in history and they do execute. I can see the text if I copy-paste it somewhere.

How can I make the command window text visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the font from Courier to another type. In my case, I changed it to Andale Mono. I have Octave version 4.2.2, and my Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS. It is EDIT->Preferences->Terminal->Font.

This is the fixed command window. 
[image]

This is the past bugged command window.
[image]